# BluetoothGattCallback processing data slow from BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am reading BLE Data from a device that updates a characteristic every 25ms, then android gets notified every 25ms through **onCharacteristicChanged()** callback.

Since I do reading and writing calls simultaneously, I have implemented a queue **Queue(Runnable)** so I do not miss any read/write command that I add to the queue with every **onCharacteristicChanged()** callback.

As the queue of runnables gets processed, I am using **onCharacteristicWrite()** and **onCharacteristicRead()** to perform the reading/writing operation of no more than 20 bits.

The problem is the asynchronous ble callbacks **onCharacteristicWrite(**) and **onCharacteristicRead()** are very slow and process one runnable for the queue only every 100ms. Since I get new data every 25ms, the queue gets only longer and longer...

How can I do to speed up the processing time for ble callbacks? My code inside **onCharacteristicRead()** and **onCharacteristicWrite()** is basically read the bits and broadcast them in the app, nothing heavy, so I wonder if it is an android limitation.

Thank you for help!

Comment: When you get onCharacteristicChanged, the notified data can be immediately retrieved by calling getValue() on the characteristic. If you write (with response) or perform a read, then a full roundtrip to the remote device is required. Why do you write / read? Isn't the data you need already in the notified value?

Comment: Hi Emil, I have a readCharacteristic that reads a timer every 25ms and a writeCharacteristic that can start/pause/stop the time. If I do not use the write/read with response in a queue, when I write it is busy reading and the start/pause/stop function is lost. Then I implemented a queue of runnables and that doesn't miss any command. However requires to have every read/write in a list waiting for onCharacteristicWrite() or onCharacteristicRead() to be dropped from the queue and slowing the roundtrip to 100ms not being able to process data every 25ms. Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: When data comes in, you receive the call on a Binder thread. Make sure you get of it as soon as possible because Android will not deliver the 'next' callback until you are off it. Typically you do this by posting the 'value' you receive on a handler for handling. However, I don't think you'll ever get to 20ms for a read since it has to do a full roundtrip to the peripheral and back.

Comment: Normally, if you need to receive data that quick, notifications are used and you can get to those speeds. But with reads and writes it will probably not work...

Comment: Just like Martijn says, please don't execute one gatt request every 25 ms. BLE is not made for this and a request will take longer time to complete. It usually takes two connection intervals per request (2 x 50 ms). To stream data from the peripheral, use notifications and embed the data since those do not require any roundtrip.

Comment: Hello Emil and Martijn, I have followed your recommendations and I am using only notifications for read but still using queue with roundtrip for writes following Martijn van Welie post:https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-3-117d3a8aee23

The reason is that I disable notifications for read, then perform the write queue and when there is zero items, I enable the read notification again with onCharacteristicWrite() . This procure lets me write commands and the reads every 25ms don't block the gatt. Thank you both!